# Is there a way to create the bean class from a json response

Tags: java, json, gson

[Converting JSON to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182)

The above question is with reference to what has been described on the above thread. There are so many API(s) which provide the flexibility to return responses either in XML or JSON. **I would like to know if there is a way to automatically construct the java bean corresponding to a JSON response. **

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate Java class from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

lets say you get an object like

```
    [
        {
        "name":"Java 6 Greatest Hits",
        "Author":"Jim Bob Jones",
        "price":10.25
        },
        {
        "name":"How to raise a goat",
        "Author":"Sir Paxton",
        "price":55.97   
        },
        {
        "name":"Snow - It is cold",
        "Author":"Dr. White",
        "price":9.99    
        }
   ]
```

And you want a class like

```
public class Book{
    private String author;
    private String name;
    private Number price
}
```

with getters and setters
One option is to use a service like [JSONGen](http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/), which will create that class. You need to use it *first*, and include the generated code in your project.
Another option could be dynamically generate the class using javassist or CGLib, but that class would be useless unless you use reflection to access its members, so even if it *would* be a class, it will *behave* like a really annoying Map. In no way will be better that simple using [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Answer (score 8):

seems a simple Message Type Entity not meet you requirement ?

**if you want convert a json to an existed and known java bean class,**

many lib can do so, like

http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/class-use/JSONObject.html

```
 JSONObject.toBean(JSONObject jsonObject, Class beanClass)
      Creates a bean from a JSONObject, with a specific target class.
```

btw, if you are communicating with  restful webservice, org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  will help you get direct bean result 
insteadof json.

**if class does not exists, you need program with java reflect mechanism.** 
try use CGLIB ,http://cglib.sourceforge.net/, dynamic create  some class like BeanMap.  i wrote a simple sample,
but be ware, opearting class byte is hard and you may meet strange trouble with JVM . Strongly not encourage to do so.

```
  public static BeanMap generateBean(JSONObject json) {
    BeanGenerator generator = new BeanGenerator();

    Iterator keys = json.keys();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        Object key = keys.next();
        Object value = json.get(key);
        Class keyClass = guessValueClass(value);
        generator.addProperty(key.toString(), keyClass);

    }

    Object result = generator.create();
    BeanMap bean = BeanMap.create(result);
    keys = json.keys();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        Object key = keys.next();
        Object value = json.get(key);
        bean.put(key, value);
    }

    return bean;
}

/**
 * TODO fix guess
 */
static Class guessValueClass(Object value) {

    try {
        Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        return Integer.class;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {

    }
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(value.toString());
        return Double.class;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {

    }
    return String.class;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the main issue here is that the JSON response *lacks type information* and last time I checked :-) in Java you need to declare the type of a class property. So some heuristics will be needed to infer the type form the value in the JSON response.

For a related question here in SO have a look at: [Generate Java class from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json)

Answer (score 2):

Yes check out http://flexjson.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to generate Java classes from JSON, perhaps you could try [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). It provides a lot of JSON-related functionality, including the ability to generate bytecode from arbitrary JSON. See [this blog post](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/08/entry_459.html) for details.

Comment: trying to generate bytecode seems to be done based on an existing class. not sure if it would be possible to generate a java class given a JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jackson (the most popular library there), try

https://bitbucket.org/astav/jsontojava/wiki/Home

Its open source and anyone should be able to contribute.

Summary

A JsonToJava source class file generator that deduces the schema based on supplied sample json data and generates the necessary java data structures.

It encourages teams to think in Json first, before writing actual code.

Features

Can generate classes for an arbitrarily complex hierarchy (recursively)
Can read your existing Java classes and if it can deserialize into those structures, will do so
Will prompt for user input when ambiguous cases exist

Comment: This code generator project was very helpful - easy to setup, use, & saved me a lot of time .. thanks!

Comment: For my assignment, it is not an open source project - so the GPL license in Jackson means I can't use that JSON library.  The way I got around that was to swap Jackson's annotation "@JsonProperty" with Gson's "@SerializedName" and all worked fine.