# How to create an object class that can converted to json like this in java?

Tags: java

This is the JSON request that I need to pass to other API, My problem is I dont know how to create an object that can have other object inside.

What is the best approach for this, I'll be using ObjectMapper to convert the object into json like this.

```
{
    "request": {
        "head": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "function": "sample.function",
            "clientId": "clientId",
            "clientSecret": "clientSecret",
            "reqTime": "2001-07-04T12:08:56+05:30",
            "reqMsgId": "reqMessageID",
            "reserve": ""
        },
        "body": {
            "occurTime": "2018-03-04T12:08:56+08:00",
            "bizScene": "SAMPLE_BIZ",
            "envInfo": {
                "tokenId": "jkahsdhsjakdhkjsajdsahdkjsakdhsa===",
                "clientIp": "127.0.0.1",
                "appVersion": "v0.1.0",
                "terminalType": "NOP"
            },
            "extendInfo": {
                "PSID":"87943297427",
                "PSID_CreatedDate":"2018-01-04T12:08:56+08:00",
                "mobtelLinkingDate" : "2018-03-04T12:08:56+08:00",
                "mobtelUnlinkingDate" : "2018-04-04T12:08:56+08:00",
                "activeLinkedMobtel" : "123756"
            },
            "accountInfo": {
                "userMobile": "123756"
            },
            "operationInfoDTO" : {
                 "operationOrigin": "TWEETER",
            },
            "operationType": "SAMPLE",
            "operationResult": "FALSE",
        }
    },
    "signature": "signature string"
}
```

Comment: try this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni
there is too many object inside an object I just want to know what is the best approach in doing this.

Comment: @Rajat its not working upon pasting my json

Comment: @KimbrielOraya You need to have a schema for your objects. What you have is a sample json

Comment: @KimbrielOraya Select source type as JSON at http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to create the bean class from a json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440212/is-there-a-way-to-create-the-bean-class-from-a-json-response)

Answer (score 0):

I gave a name to the root Object a used [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) website to generate boilerplate bean object

```
"rootObj":{
    "request": {
        "head": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "function": "sample.function",
            "clientId": "clientId",
            "clientSecret": "clientSecret",
            "reqTime": "2001-07-04T12:08:56+05:30",
            "reqMsgId": "reqMessageID",
            "reserve": ""
        },
        "body": {
            "occurTime": "2018-03-04T12:08:56+08:00",
            "bizScene": "SAMPLE_BIZ",
            "envInfo": {
                "tokenId": "jkahsdhsjakdhkjsajdsahdkjsakdhsa===",
                "clientIp": "127.0.0.1",
                "appVersion": "v0.1.0",
                "terminalType": "NOP"
            },
            "extendInfo": {
                "PSID":"87943297427",
                "PSID_CreatedDate":"2018-01-04T12:08:56+08:00",
                "mobtelLinkingDate" : "2018-03-04T12:08:56+08:00",
                "mobtelUnlinkingDate" : "2018-04-04T12:08:56+08:00",
                "activeLinkedMobtel" : "123756"
            },
            "accountInfo": {
                "userMobile": "123756"
            },
            "operationInfoDTO" : {
                 "operationOrigin": "TWEETER",
            },
            "operationType": "SAMPLE",
            "operationResult": "FALSE",
        }
    },
    "signature": "signature string"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor syntax errors in your JSON example in line 33 and 36.

JSON doesn't like comma after the last element of a list or dictionary.

If you remove those and use this JSON as input for http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ you'll get corresponding Java classes.