# storing and breaking character stream in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, char

I have some characters as-

```
{"user_id":"7178717","firstname":"John","lastname":"Daniel","email":"test@example.com"}
```

Please some one tell me how to first represent/store these characters as it is in Java program ie can I represent these characters in enum or some array or some type etc. I need to know the type to represent or store this stream of characters
  And how to break these in occurrence of coma ie ','
I want to write an application in Java 8edn

Answer (score 2):

It looks like JSON, you can use for eg. [json.org](http://www.json.org/java/index.html). If you want to parse it as string you can use split function with "," as parameter which makes you array of strings. eg. string.split(",")

Comment: But split() of String act on String objects. And this whole sequence could not be stored in String class variable or String []. Breaking and splitting I know but first how to take this sequence in java prog ? this is 1st ques.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to define a class which has these fields e.g.:

```
long user_id;
String firstname;
String lastname;
String email;
```

You can try using this library to parse your input.

[gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json) . However , [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) is the easiest way to generate  java class from json data.