# JSON to pojo conversion

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have json where some of the field names are camel case some of the field names start with capital letter and some are completely upper case. JSON I am dealing with is highly nested and some times field names are repeated based on depth of the node when you convert nested json into tree.

Is there any easy way to generate POJO for this kind of JSON.

Comment: Have you heard of [this website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) ?

Comment: @JsonProperty if you use Jackson

Comment: I am using that library through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380069/jsonschema2pojo-not-generating-pojo-classes-from-json-string but I still face problem if the field name is not camel case. is there any way I can ask the library to attach     @JsonProperty("FieldName") before every field?

Comment: @SlimSoltaniDridi commented

Comment: @Raptor commented

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ ? so are u using jackson ?

Comment: I am using org.jsonschema2pojo library to create pojos through code. Yes it indeed uses jackson @SlimSoltaniDridi