# convert json string to Java source code not working

Tags: java, jackson2

I have a dynamic JSON schema that I need to convert to Java source code at run-time
I found this Jackson example that seems very [common](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.jsonschema2pojo.DefaultGenerationConfig)
The code is running fine, no exceptions but not generating anything.
When I break the json structure (just to test that jackson is working) I do get Jackson exception...

```
@Test
public void jsonToJava() throws IOException {   
    JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();
    String schemaContents ="{\"test\":\"test\"}";

    GenerationConfig config = new DefaultGenerationConfig() {
        @Override
        public boolean isGenerateBuilders() { 
            return true;
        }
    };

    SchemaMapper mapper = new SchemaMapper(new RuleFactory(config, new Jackson2Annotator(config), new SchemaStore()), new SchemaGenerator());
    mapper.generate(codeModel, "HelloWorldClass", "com.my.package", schemaContents);
    File directory = new File("C:\\temp\\gen");
    directory.mkdirs();
    codeModel.build(directory);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about that library, but it appears the example doesn't work as is.  According to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380069/jsonschema2pojo-not-generating-pojo-classes-from-json-string), you need to override another method in your DefaultGenerationConfig to get this to work.  Adding the following code to your example worked for me:

```
@Override
public SourceType getSourceType() {
    return SourceType.JSON;
}
```