# How can i obtain domain class of a collection in spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I transferred a `table` from `postgresql` to `mongodb`.I want to map this `collection` to a `class`. Is there a easy way to create the `class` of this `collection` ?

Comment: Do you want automatically generate a new class? or do you want to use already exists java class ?

Comment: I want it to be automatically generated @Oleg

Answer (score 0):

Well,
If you already created mongo DB. you could use java classes generator for json.
All documents in mongodb are represented in json.
Look at the answers for this question [Generate Java class from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json)

Comment: But what i want to ask is different from this answer. I transffered a table from mysql to mongodb. I want to create mapped class to this collection. Is there a way for this operation ? @Oleg