# How can I create a JSON Object using JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

How can I recreate the following JSON object, in Javausing `JSONObject`?

```
{  
   "RequestorId":121,
   "Groups":[  
      {  
         "GroupID":1,
         "GroupName":"xyz",
         "ContentGroup":"abc",
         "Regions":"india",
         "MarketsCovered":"all",
         "Users":[  
            {  
               "UserId":101,
               "FirstName":"aaa",
               "LastName":"yyy",
               "Work_Location":"blore",
               "CurrentRole":"ccc",
               "LanguageSkills":"english"
            },
            {  
               "UserId":102,
               "FirstName":"bbb",
               "LastName":"vvv",
               "Work_Location":"blore",
               "CurrentRole":"ttt",
               "LanguageSkills":"urdu"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "GroupID":2,
         "GroupName":"yyy",
         "ContentGroup":"bca",
         "Regions":"india",
         "MarketsCovered":"kkk",
         "Users":[  
            {  
               "UserId":108,
               "FirstName":"hhh",
               "LastName":"jjj",
               "Work_Location":"blore",
               "CurrentRole":"ggg",
               "LanguageSkills":"english"
            },
            {  
               "UserId":333,
               "FirstName":"rrr",
               "LastName":"eee",
               "Work_Location":"mandya",
               "CurrentRole":"ddd",
               "LanguageSkills":"english"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json

Answer (score 0):

You can work your way from the inner objects to the outer objects, i.e. from Users to Groups, by using the method `JSONObject.put(String, Object)`. Object can be an array of other JSON objects, so you can build up the hierarchy (`JSONObject.put(String, Collection)` should work as well).

To give you an idea:

```
    JSONObject user1 = new JSONObject().put("UserId", 101).put("FirstName", "aaa"); // Create user1
    JSONObject user2 = new JSONObject().put("UserId", 102).put("FirstName", "bbb"); // Create user2

    // Now create a group and nest the two users within the group
    JSONObject groups1 = new JSONObject().put("GroupId", 1).put("GroupName", "xyz");

    // Nest users by using an array of JSON objects
    groups1.put("Users", new JSONObject[] { user1, user2 });
```