# Retrofit Body returning null

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

Im using retrofit to get connect with a database, but the GSON seems to not be parsing the data. The JSON is being returned but the response body is not being created, so i can not interact with the data. Any ideas?

My URL addition

```
public interface APIPlug {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("repair_manager/v1/login")
Call<UserResults>Login(
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password
        );


}
```

My Retrofit builder

```
public class ApiClient {

private static APIPlug REST_CLIENT;
private static final String API_URL = "http://192.168.1.85/";

static {
    setupRestClient();
}

private ApiClient() {}

public static APIPlug get() {
    return REST_CLIENT;
}

private static void setupRestClient() {

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    //Uncomment these lines below to start logging each request.


    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();


    REST_CLIENT = retrofit.create(APIPlug.class);
}}
```

User.java

```
public class User {

    private Boolean error;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String apiKey;

    private String createdAt;



    public Boolean getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

}
```

The activity to use use the GSON

```
 private void getUser() {

    final String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
Call<UserResults> call = ApiClient.get().Login(email,password);

call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResults>() {

    public void onFailure(Call<UserResults> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("APIPlug", "Error Occured: " + t.getMessage());

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

public void onResponse(Call<UserResults> call, Response<UserResults> response) {
    Log.d("APIPlug", "Successfully response fetched" );

    pDialog.dismiss();

    user = response.body().results;


    Log.d("APIPlug", String.valueOf(response.body().results));

    session.setLogin(true);}});
```

User result

```
public class UserResults {
public List<User> results;}
```

okhttp log

```
08-15 21:18:32.753 13629-14006/com.example.maxwell.nfc_app D/OkHttp: Date: Mon, 15 Aug 2016 20:18:26 GMT
08-15 21:18:32.753 13629-14006/com.example.maxwell.nfc_app D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19
08-15 21:18:32.753 13629-14006/com.example.maxwell.nfc_app D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.19
08-15 21:18:32.753 13629-14006/com.example.maxwell.nfc_app D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 148
08-15 21:18:32.753 13629-14006/com.example.maxwell.nfc_app D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
08-15 21:18:32.753 13629-14006/com.example.maxwell.nfc_app D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
08-15 21:18:32.753 13629-14006/com.example.maxwell.nfc_app D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
08-15 21:18:32.753 13629-14006/com.example.maxwell.nfc_app D/OkHttp: {"error":false,"name":"Rachel Simon","email":"RachelSimon2@gmail.com","apiKey":"c5996a2076d7338987d8743effc56d58","createdAt":"2016-08-13 12:41:51"}
08-15 21:18:32.753 13629-14006/com.example.maxwell.nfc_app D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (148-byte body)
```

Comment: User class and UserResults are different?

Comment: user result: public class UserResults {
    public List<User> results;

}

Comment: Inside ```onResponse```, you should first do an ```if``` statement using ```response.isSuccess()```. Does this return true?

Comment: Please attach the OkHttp log and an example of JSON you're trying to parse.

Comment: Yes this is successful

Comment: @egor did this help?

Comment: @Mugzwell how about use Json as response type and parse or deserialize to your class ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not retrieving a list of `User` object but just one in this case... Thats why it's not deserialized into your `POJO`. You expect UserResults which is a list but you just retrieved a single object.

```
Call<UserResults> call = ApiClient.get().Login(email,password);
```

Should become :

```
Call<User> call = ApiClient.get().Login(email,password);
```

Or if the expected behavior is to retrieve an array, then you should handle on the server side to always send an array even when there is just one elements... What I do to avoid all error is to create my pojo with this website : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [JaythaKing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3457218/jaythaking) you are receiving JSONObject and not JSONArray as a response. So use Call and not Call.

For starting in Retrofit I suggest you go through this:

[Consuming APIs with Retrofit](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit#automated-approach---auto-generating-the-java-objects)

And learning JSON Basics and Parsing:

[Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

As option, you can receive your response as Json and after that parse it or deserialize by [any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json) method to your class.

```
public interface APIPlug {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("repair_manager/v1/login")
Call<JsonElement>Login(
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password
        );
```

Request:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
            JsonObject objectWhichYouNeed = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

            //use any json deserializer to convert to your class.
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(response.message());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }
});
```