# Convert from normal string to json string and then to bean

Tags: java, json

I have the following string

```
    String new_value=
   {
        product_type_id: 1,
        product_cat_id: 1,
        product_type_nm: PED
    }, {
        product_type_id: 2,
        product_cat_id: 2,
        product_type_nm: MOBILE APP
    }, {
        product_type_id: 3,
        product_cat_id: 1,
        product_type_nm: MOBILE
    }, {
        product_type_id: 4,
        product_cat_id: 3,
        product_type_nm: PAYMENT
    }, {
        product_type_id: 5,
        product_cat_id: 5,
        product_type_nm: USER
    }, {
        product_type_id: 6,
        product_cat_id: 6,
        product_type_nm: SMS
    }, {
        product_type_id: 9,
        product_cat_id: 6,
        product_type_nm: EMAIL
    }, {
        product_type_id: 10,
        product_cat_id: 6,
        product_type_nm: TOPUP
    }
```

This String contains data related to many beans.
I want to convert it into json string and then into bean in java.How can i do it?
I am using

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(new_value);
```

Is it possible with this.

Comment: Make it into a JSON array like `[ <your string> ]` then loop through it and deserialize each member of the array as the bean (using jackson databind ObjectMapper for example).

Comment: above string miss start and end {} .

Comment: actually, json string is not a valid string.Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use use Jackson to convert Java object to / from JSON

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'vinit'}";
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Staff.class); //String to Class Object
```

Before that you need to add `jackson-databind` lib.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

you can see more example on [click here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below link:

[Generate Java class from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json)

They are converting a Json to POJO. There are multiple tools available online and you can download the same once done.If there are any exceptions, share the trace logs and someone can help.