# Java Parse JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I try to parse JSON below with java Jackson library but I not able to get the value at level "ChannelType", "Address" and etc. It is because of value "endpoint123" &  "endppoint456", which cause some problem for me. I try to google but can't find elsewhere.
Would like some 1 expert here to assist. Thanks in advance.

```
    {
    "Message": {},
    "ApplicationId": "aaa",
    "CampaignId": "bbb",
    "TreatmentId": "0",
    "ActivityId": "ccc",
    "ScheduledTime": "2021-04-07T08:43:16.406Z",
    "Endpoints": {
        "endpointa123": {
            "ChannelType": "CUSTOM",
            "Address": "bobby@abc.com.my",
            "EndpointStatus": "ACTIVE",
            "OptOut": "NONE",
            "EffectiveDate": "2021-04-07T08:35:48.796Z",
            "User": {
                "UserAttributes": {
                    "Custom4": [
                        "data4"
                    ],
                    "Custom3": [
                        "data3"
                    ],
                    "Custom2": [
                        "data2"
                    ],
                    "Custom1": [
                        "data1"
                    ],
                    "Custom5": [
                        "data5"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "CreationDate": "2021-04-07T08:35:48.796Z"
        },
        "endpoint456": {
            "ChannelType": "CUSTOM",
            "Address": "fifis@abc.com.my",
            "EndpointStatus": "ACTIVE",
            "OptOut": "NONE",
            "EffectiveDate": "2021-04-07T08:35:48.792Z",
            "User": {
                "UserAttributes": {
                    "Custom4": [
                        "data4"
                    ],
                    "Custom3": [
                        "data3"
                    ],
                    "Custom2": [
                        "data2"
                    ],
                    "Custom1": [
                        "data1"
                    ],
                    "Custom5": [
                        "data5"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "CreationDate": "2021-04-07T08:35:48.792Z"
        }
    }
}
```

My code as per below, Campaign is my own define class.

```
            Campaign campaign = mapper.readValue(json, Campaign.class);
            String valueOut =  mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(campaign);
            System.out.println(valueOut);
```

My Java Object Model for the above as per below.

```
Campaign 
   |--EndPoints
       |-- EndPointsContainer (Array) 
            |--User 
                 |--UserAttributes
```

Following is result which I get.

```
"Message" : { },
"ApplicationId" : "aaa",
"CampaignId" : "bbb",
"TreatmentId" : "0",
"ActivityId" : "ccc",
"ScheduledTime" : "2021-04-07T10:44:27.598Z",
"EndPoints" : {
"endPointsContainer" : [ ],
"creationDate" : null,
"CreationDate" : null
```

Thanks for @Robert. It at least quite similar with original JSON.
POJO was reconstruct as per below.

```
Campaign 
   |--EndPoints
        |--User 
             |--UserAttributes
```

However, CreationDate is inside object "endpoint123" and "endpoint456", instead of outside. Because it is lengthy. I posted part of it.

```
"ScheduledTime": "2021-04-07T08:43:16.406Z",
"Endpoints": {
    "endpointa123": {
        "CreationDate": "2021-04-07T08:35:48.796Z"
        "ChannelType": "CUSTOM",
```

Comment: How does your object look like? It seems you need a `Map<String, Object>` and also, the result you've posted is not a valid JSON

Comment: In your sample data there are no arrays. `Endpoints` seems to be a `Map<String,Endpoint>`.

Comment: @Robert, thanks for your reply. At least it is quite same as original JSON. I remove "EndPointsContainer (Array)" from my model. Move all json properties in EndPointsContainer to EndPoints.  Define Map<String, Endpoint> as per your suggestion. Only 1 thing. "Creation Date" was inside object "endpoint123" and "endpoint456" instead of outside.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here,

1. The JSON is not in correct format. If you expect the `enpoints` to be an array and that to be with variable name `endPointsContainer`, you need to have same name. `endpointa123` and `endpoint456` will be treated as different objects and wont be part of single list
2. Variable `CreationDate` is part of endpoint and hence it will available inside the `endPointsContainer`

So the correct JSON as per your expectation would be,

```
{
  "Message": {},
  "ApplicationId": "aaa",
  "CampaignId": "bbb",
  "TreatmentId": "0",
  "ActivityId": "ccc",
  "ScheduledTime": "2021-04-07T08:43:16.406Z",
  "Endpoints": {
    "endPointsContainer": [
      {
        "endpoint": {
          "ChannelType": "CUSTOM",
          "Address": "bobby@abc.com.my",
          "EndpointStatus": "ACTIVE",
          "OptOut": "NONE",
          "EffectiveDate": "2021-04-07T08:35:48.796Z",
          "User": {
            "UserAttributes": {
              "Custom4": [
                "data4"
              ],
              "Custom3": [
                "data3"
              ],
              "Custom2": [
                "data2"
              ],
              "Custom1": [
                "data1"
              ],
              "Custom5": [
                "data5"
              ]
            }
          },
          "CreationDate": "2021-04-07T08:35:48.796Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "endpoint": {
          "ChannelType": "CUSTOM",
          "Address": "fifis@abc.com.my",
          "EndpointStatus": "ACTIVE",
          "OptOut": "NONE",
          "EffectiveDate": "2021-04-07T08:35:48.792Z",
          "User": {
            "UserAttributes": {
              "Custom4": [
                "data4"
              ],
              "Custom3": [
                "data3"
              ],
              "Custom2": [
                "data2"
              ],
              "Custom1": [
                "data1"
              ],
              "Custom5": [
                "data5"
              ]
            }
          },
          "CreationDate": "2021-04-07T08:35:48.792Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I deserialized this in to MAP class,

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Object> compaign = jsonMapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
```

this is how it looks like,

[image]

Comment: thanks for your assist. However, I not able to modify this JSON. This is original JSON generated by AWS Pinpoint. I can't  modify anything on the JSON generated by AWS Pinpoint.

Comment: @Sean you need to change the object structure. You wont be able to get the endPoint array since they have different names. They will be treated as different objects. I suggest you to check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json.
this will help you to generate POJO using the JSON