# Working with heterogenous map as it was typed in Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, kotlin, types, hashmap

I read some items from DB as JSON and create a Map<String, Any> from each of them. I want to process the items as Map because instantiating objects using Jackson Object Mapper's .convertValue took a long time (decimals of milliseconds more than with Map, per item). However, the type of the map is not uniform and when I need to for example get some nested prop (e.g. `map.child.prop`), I need to go like this:

```
val prop = (parentMap["child"] as Map<String, Any>)["prop"]
```

I am aware there is Apache Commons providing `PropertyUtils.getProperty(map, "map.child.prop"))`, but it is not exactly what I want. The object is quite complex and I need to work with the whole map as it was typed. Is there such an option? The casting goes crazy as the item is a big map, but currently the only solution I have.

What I tried:

1. Convert map to class

- Too long

2. Using typed map library https://github.com/broo2s/typedmap

- The map type seems to be built continuously as you add some key/value. But I am not building continuously, I am converting from JSON.

3. Using Kotlin delegated properties

- Works well for flat structure, but needs to casting when going deeper.

Comment: Generally speaking, no.  You really need to convert the entire deep map to a full concrete type.

Comment: How big is this JSON? If it is not very big and the data structure doesn't change often, then you can just re-create the data structure and use one of serialization frameworks that provide object mapping (e.g.: kotlinx-serialization, jackson, gson). If the data structure is big and/or it changes, I believe there are some tools that generate typed data structures from JSON. Unfortunately, I can't suggest any specific one.

Comment: There are some suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json

Comment: The JSON itself is not too big. It could have about 30 props, including nested, and it has some multi-level nested maps/lists inside. The problem is I need to process thousands of them for the request, so each millisecond in processing a single item counts. Generating a class from JSON is not what I need, since I know the type in advance and as I said, instantiating objects is slow. And when working with Map I need to cast, which is ugly and also takes some time, because it's not implicit.

Comment: So honestly, I'm not sure what do you need ;-) Deserializing to classes shouldn't be slower than deserializing to map. I think it would be even faster. If for some reason you have to keep it as a map then you can create classes that wrap this map. You can make it easier by using property delegation to map: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not faster. It took 327 millis converting 5k items to objects vs 232 to map (Jackson object mapper). The closest I could get in optimization is using property delegation, but here I need to cast when working with arrays.