# Avoid generating duplicated classes with jsonschema2pojo and sourceType "json"

Tags: java, json, maven, jsonschema2pojo

Following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480636/3180809), I use the jsonschema2pojo Maven plugin to generate Java classes from JSON example files.

My JSON example file has a structure like this

```json
{
  "coffeeTable": {
    "book": [
      {
        "author": "Aldo Rossi",
        "title": "The Architecture of the City"
      }
    ]
  },
  "bookCase": [
    {
      "book": [
        {
          "author": "Shakespeare",
          "title": "Collected Works"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When generating Java classes from the JSON example, a class `Book` and a class `Book__1` is generated. `Book` is used for the books on the coffee table. `Book__1` is used for the elements in the book case.
I saw that there are solutions for avoiding duplicated classes when [generating Java classes with JSON schema files in the documentation](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Reference).
I did not find a solution when using a JSON object directly for code generation.
Is it possible to achieve that there is only a single `Book` class, which is used in both places,  generated from the JSON object above? Or do I have to create a JSON schema object from the JSON object and then use the `javaType`/`existingJavaType` annotation there to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in this case is make 2 separate json schemas and reference one in the other:

room.json

```json
{
  "title": "room",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "room.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "coffeeTable": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "book.json"
      }
    },
    "bookCase": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "book.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and book.json

```json
{
    "title": "Book",
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "book.json",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "author": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

This will generate 2 java file: `Room.java` & `Book.java`

Comment: Thanks but my question was concerning the generation from JSON examples, not JSON schemas

Comment: Sorry miss read the question. Cant help you there, I'm not using it in that way.